# ListView check and uncheck item logic

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set a `ListView` item as checked on first click, then click again to uncheck, which I have working below. The problem is, if I click the item 3 times, I am left with an unchecked item instead of a checked item as the user expects (1st click: checked, 2nd click: unchecked, 3rd click: checked, and so on..)

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

        if(position == Constants.lastSelection) {
            list.setItemChecked(position, false);
        } else {
            list.setItemChecked(position, true);
            Constants.lastSelection = position;
        }
```

I have tried some other logic that will toggle checked/unchecked on each click of an already checked item, but of course that causes issues when the user inevitably clicks random items, some items many times, etc

Any ideas on where to start? Thanks!

**Edit:**
`Constants.lastSelection` is not set before this

Comment: there is at least `list.setItemChecked(Constants.lastPosition, false);` missing.

Comment: also, is this a multiple choice or a single choice? also, there is `getCheckedItemIds` and `getCheckedItemPositions` that you can use. (that makes `Constants.lastSelection` probably useless)

Comment: What about `list.setItemChecked(position, !list.isItemChecked(position));` ?

Comment: @njzk2 It is Single Choice. Looking into those thanks

Comment: @Hyperion I'm not using `setItemChecked()` to set the items, they just become checked/selected when using `list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.chimmerltd.chimmer.ChimmerActivity.CommomImageLoader;
import com.chimmerltd.chimmer.R;
import com.chimmerltd.customControls.ChimmerRoundedImageView;
import com.chimmerltd.customControls.ChimmerTextView;
import com.chimmerltd.models.AuthenticationResponse;
import com.chimmerltd.models.ContactSynRequestcontacts;
import com.chimmerltd.models.ContactSynResponse;
import com.chimmerltd.utility.Constants;

public class SyncContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactSynResponse> {

    private Context context;
    public String type = null;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
    private List<ContactSynResponse> mList;
    List<ContactSynRequestcontacts> contactdata;


    public SyncContactsAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            List<ContactSynResponse> getdata) {
        super(context, resource, getdata);
        this.context = context;

        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();

    }

    @Override
    public ContactSynResponse getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    public ArrayList<ContactSynResponse> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<ContactSynResponse> mTempArry = new ArrayList<ContactSynResponse>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
            if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                ContactSynResponse data = mList.get(i);

                mTempArry.add(data);

            }
        }

        return mTempArry;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        ChimmerTextView contactname;
        ChimmerTextView contactno;
        ChimmerTextView unblockfriendTV;
        RelativeLayout completelayout;
        CheckBox selectcheckbox;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.sharedcontactlistdata,
                    parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();


            viewHolder.contactname = (ChimmerTextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.contactnameTV);
            viewHolder.contactno = (ChimmerTextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.contactnoTV);
            viewHolder.completelayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.completeRL);
            viewHolder.selectcheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.contact_checkbox);

            viewHolder.unblockfriendTV = (ChimmerTextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.unblockfriendTV);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.BLOCK_CONTACT)) {
                viewHolder.selectcheckbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ContactSynResponse data = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.contactname.setText(data.getName());
        viewHolder.contactno.setText(data.getPhone());
        viewHolder.selectcheckbox.setTag(position);

        viewHolder.selectcheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckchangeListener(data,
                        viewHolder.selectcheckbox));
        if (data.isSelected()) {
            viewHolder.selectcheckbox
                    .setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.notification_selected_checkbox);
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) viewHolder.selectcheckbox.getTag(), data.isSelected());
        } else {
            viewHolder.selectcheckbox
                    .setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.notification_checkbox);
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) viewHolder.selectcheckbox.getTag(), data.isSelected());
        }

        if (data.getIsBlocked() == 1) {
            viewHolder.unblockfriendTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            viewHolder.unblockfriendTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }

        viewHolder.completelayout.setOnClickListener(new CompleteLayoutClickListener(data,viewHolder.selectcheckbox));
        return convertView;

    }

    class CompleteLayoutClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        private ContactSynResponse data;
        private CheckBox checkbox;
        public CompleteLayoutClickListener(ContactSynResponse  data,CheckBox checkbox) {
        this.data=data;
        this.checkbox=checkbox;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
if(data.isSelected())
{
data.setSelected(false);
checkbox.setChecked(false);
mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) checkbox.getTag(), false);
}
else
{
    data.setSelected(true);
    checkbox.setChecked(true);
    mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) checkbox.getTag(), true);
}
        }

    }

    class CheckchangeListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

        private CheckBox checkbox;
        private ContactSynResponse data;

        public CheckchangeListener(ContactSynResponse data, CheckBox checkbox) {

            this.checkbox = checkbox;
            this.data = data;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                checkbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.notification_selected_checkbox);
            } else {
                checkbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.notification_checkbox);
            }
            buttonView.setChecked(isChecked);
            data.setSelected(isChecked);
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);

        }
    }

}


model class :-

public class ContactSynResponse {

    private long id;
    private long UserId;
    private String Name;
    private String Phone;
    private String ProfilePhoto;
    private int isBlocked;
    private boolean isSelected;

    private Bitmap profileBitmap;


    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public String getProfilePhoto() {
        return ProfilePhoto;
    }

    public void setProfilePhoto(String profilePhoto) {
        ProfilePhoto = profilePhoto;
    }

    public int getIsBlocked() {
        return isBlocked;
    }

    public void setIsBlocked(int isBlocked) {
        this.isBlocked = isBlocked;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public Bitmap getProfileBitmap() {
        return profileBitmap;
    }

    public void setProfileBitmap(Bitmap profileBitmap) {
        this.profileBitmap = profileBitmap;
    }

}


layout used:-


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/completeRL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactnameTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/profilepic_image_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profilepic_image_view"
        android:text="@string/about" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactnoTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profilepic_image_view"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contactnameTV"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="@string/about" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/contact_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/contactnameTV"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:button="@drawable/notification_checkbox" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unblockfriendTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contactnoTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/unblock_friend_message"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/grey" />

</RelativeLayout>
```